# json.load for not allowing nan and inf values load

Tags: python, python-3.x

As appears in documentation in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#infinite-and-nan-number-values)
Could somebody give example how exactly to use `parse_constant` with `json.load` in order to
avoid loading of `inf`, `-inf`, `nan` values which will raise some `Value error` exception such is done easily when doing `json.dumps(allow_nan=False)`

Much appreciated

Comment: parse_constant, if specified, will be called with one of the following strings: '-Infinity', 'Infinity', 'NaN'. This can be used to raise an exception if invalid JSON numbers are encountered.[same page you linked to, just did a ctrl+F for `parse_constant`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)

Answer (score 1):

if it's not clear from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load):

> parse_constant, if specified, will be called with one of the following
> strings: '-Infinity', 'Infinity', 'NaN'. This can be used to raise an
> exception if invalid JSON numbers are encountered.

This means it's a function called with one of those 3 strings as argument and should return appropriate value (or throw an error I assume)

```
def test(arg):
    print("got:",arg)
    c = {"-Infinity":-float("inf"), "Infinity":float("inf"), "NaN":float("nan")}
    return c[arg]

json.loads('[Infinity, -Infinity, NaN]', parse_constant=test)
```

So to ensure it never loads those I think your function would just `raise ValueError("not allowed Infinity or NaN")` or similar.