# Converting Panda's float32 and float64 to Python's native float and loss of accuracy

Tags: python, pandas

I need to serialise some Pandas DataFrame data for storing in the JSON. For this purpose I am converting `float32` and `float64` data types to native Python `float`.

- Will there be implications for the data accuracy, or can Python `float` correctly prevent both of these Pandas data types?
- Could there be other issues e.g. with `NaN` and `Inf`? (note: I am already aware that strict [JSON does not handle `Inf` serialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62678653/json-load-for-not-allowing-nan-and-inf-values-load))

Comment: To that end, your float number will be a string, so you'll lose precision. https://stackoverflow.com/q/27098529/15239951